# О наречии "наполовину"

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно, наречия

*Число заболевших учеников 6-11 классов в Москве уменьшилось **почти на половину.***
https://glasnarod.ru/rossiya/moskva/352473-chislo-zabolevshix-uchenikov-6-11-klassov-v-moskve-umenshilos-pochti-na-polovinu

Ну это СМИ, что с них возьмешь? А вот почему писатели стали использовать раздельную форму письма, причем их цитируют на известном сайте – вот это непонятно. [https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/уменьшиться+на+половину](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)

Кстати, один из примеров **интересный**. Если наречие пишется там слитно, но получается разное написание для сходных сочетаний:
*Гонения на остатки теократической группировки впоследствии длились без малого три года, и постепенно штат ордена по сравнению с былыми временами уменьшился **на половину**, а влияние и вовсе **на три четверти.*** Андрей Станиславович Горянов, Тень Феникса, 2020

**И вопрос:** Ничего не изменилось с написанием этого наречия в правилах и словарях, может быть, появились исключения?

Comment: В значении "в какой мере, степени" (наполовину пуст) это наречие. А так ли это в _количественных_ выражениях уменьшения/увеличения (на какую величину, часть)? Словари обычно не задаются этим вопросом, повторяя избитый пример альтернативы "середина на половину".

Comment: Книжный пример из 1877: "За это время туземная раса на половину уменьшилась..."

Comment: Можно сказать: туземная раса  уменьшилась вдвое. В этой позиции может стоять наречие, так почему бы ему там не стоять. Другое дело, когда в одной и той же конструкции неудобно использовать разные формы, например: Свертываемость проверяется раз в три месяца, она должна снижаться на одну треть или на  (одну) половину. [Николай Амосов. Голоса времен (1999)]

Comment: Не всякое наречие может. "Уменьшилась наполовину" = наполовину уменьшилась, наполовину - нет (сапоги всмятку).

Comment: Из словаря: НАПОЛОВИНУ, нареч. 1. Одной половиной; на одну половину. Уменьшить срок н.   Что здесь не так?

Comment: Разница с полупустым стаканом в том, что при уменьшении/увеличении чего-либо исчезает/добавляется половина того, что есть. "Уменьшить срок наполовину" - ошибка. _... возможно было бы уменьшить на половину меру наказания_ (Кистяковский, об отмене телесных наказаний). "На половину" = "на половину исходной величины".